# how can i make a datagrid value searchable using dexterity in plone?

Tags: plone, dexterity

I have a custom content type built with dexterity and I have a datagrid on it. What I want to do is make the fields in the datagrid searchable with plone search engine. Please provide some sample if possible. im a noob.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer

For best results I think you shold read the section "Registering a custom field converter".

In addition you may find interesting reading this similar SO question:

- [Extending SearchableText using collective.dexteritytextindexer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118350/extending-searchabletext-using-collective-dexteritytextindexer)

It's really well written and contains link to code examples in github.

Ciao